# Calculate change against past value with a tolerance in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.Series` object with a `pd.DatetimeIndex` containing dates. I would like to calculate the difference from a past value, for example the one month before. The values are not exactly aligned to the months, so I cannot simply add a monthly date offset. There might also be missing data.

So I would like to match the previous value using an offset and a tolerance. One way to do this is using the `.reindex()` method with `method='nearest'` which matches the previous data point *almost* like I want to:

```
shifted = data.copy()
shifted.index = shifted.index + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
shifted = shifted.reindex(
    data.index,
    method="nearest",
    tolerance=timedelta(days=100),
)
return data - shifted
```

Here we calculate the difference from the value one month before, but we tolerate finding a value *100 days* around that timestamp.

This is almost what I want, but I want to avoid subtracting the value from itself. I always want to subtract a value in the past, or no value at all.

For example: if this is the data

```
2020-01-02  1.0
2020-02-03  2.0
2020-04-05  3.0
```

And I use the code above, the last data point, 3.0 will be subtracted from itself, since its date is closer to `2020-05-05` than to `2020-03-03`. And the result will be

```
2020-01-02  0.0
2020-02-03  1.0
2020-04-05  0.0
```

While the goal is to get

```
2020-01-02  NaN
2020-02-03  1.0
2020-04-05  1.0
```

Additional edit after Baron Legendre's answer (thanks for pointing out the flaw in my question):

The `tolerance` variable is also important to me. So let's say there is a gap of a year in the data, that falls outside the tolerance of 100 days, and the result should be NaN:

```
2015-12-04  10.0
2020-01-02  1.0
2020-02-03  2.0
2020-04-05  3.0
```

Should result in:

```
2015-12-05  NaN (because there is no past value to subtract)
2020-01-02  NaN (because the past value is too far back)
2020-02-03  1.0
2020-04-05  1.0
```

Hope that explains the problem well enough. Any ideas on how to do this efficiently, without looping over every single data point?

Answer (score 0):

```
ser
###
2015-12-04    10
2020-01-02     1
2020-02-03     2
2020-04-05     3
dtype: int64
```

```
df = ser.reset_index()
tdiff = df['index'].diff().dt.days
ser[:] = np.where(tdiff > 100, np.nan, ser - ser.shift())
ser
###
2015-12-04    NaN
2020-01-02    NaN
2020-02-03    1.0
2020-04-05    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does indeed solve the example I provided. I was probably unclear, but matching using an offset and a tolerance is important to my use case. So I might want to match 12 months back, with a tolerance of 1 month forwards and backwards. Or 1 month back, with 7 days tolerance (it varies), but the matched value must always be in the past. I've adjusted the question with one more example.

Comment: I've updated the post, we can use `np.where` to modify the outcome.